# How can I create subsection of a component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say I have the following React component in Typescript:

```
type FooProps = React.PropsWithChildren<{}>;

export function Foo({ children }: FooProps) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

A lot of React libraries declare components of `<Foo.Bar>` type, allowing you to write the following:

```
<Foo>
  <Foo.Bar></Foo.Bar>
  <Foo.Bar></Foo.Bar>
  <Foo.Bar></Foo.Bar>
</Foo>
```

I think this is pretty nice to write, but how can I implement the same with a custom component?

I looked at the implementation in some libraries and I saw that `<Foo>` is actually implemented like

```
export const Foo = ... & {
  Bar: typeof Bar
}
```

I tried to write the following, but without success.

Comment: All you need is `Foo.Bar = Bar` after you have defined both of them. Then export with the proper types like in your example at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an example for you:

All you need is define a subsection to your Root component with RootComponent.WhateverYouNeed = Component

```js
type FooProps = React.PropsWithChildren<{ testId: string }>;

const Root = () => {
  return <div></div>;
};
const Foo = (props: FooProps) => {
  return <div data-testid={props.testId}>foo</div>;
};

const Bar = (props: { testId: string }) => {
  return <div data-testid={props.testId}>bar</div>;
};

Root.Foo = Foo;
Root.Bar = Bar;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Root />
      <Root.Bar testId="test" />
      <Root.Foo testId="test" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: And what if I have to make them children of `Root`?